# Launching Chrome Extension from an External C# Program

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ui-automation

I'm trying to start a chrome extension from an external c# program.

What I have so far:

The extension is complete and launches when the extension button is clicked.
The program searches for available chrome browsers via Process.GetProcessesByName.
Once its done it searches for the chrome extension button with the Ui-Automation dll.

I was able to drill down and find the button, but it doesn't have an Invoke pattern, or any patterns for that matter even though the control type is a button.

Goal:

I'm letting the user bind a hotkey to use as their mediakey instead of pressing fn+MediaKey.
I would also like the program to affect youtube videos, which the javascript in the extension handles. It pauses any playing videos, and plays any paused videos. I figured writing an extension and invoking a click would do it, but none of the chrome toolbar buttons seem to respond to Invoke actions.

I'd appreciate any help in pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can point some ways to do it, but it will be seen as an security issue anyway. For example you could use `registerProtocolHandler` to pass messages between your application and the extension under a custom URI but it's [being discussed as an vulnerability](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9860) and will be limited soon.

I'm afraid there's no way to bring this kind of power for a chrome extension unless you use a [NPAPI Plugin](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) and make one of these is a real pain.

The best solution I can image is making your application remap the media keys for some of the supported shortcuts by [Commands API](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/commands.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Alright, I'll try using the Commands API and see if maybe I can send the window messages. Kind of a bummer that there isn't any way to communicate with an extension externally.